# Latency between data received through Excel RTD and "Original data"

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a trading (software) program that connects to Excel (via Excel RTD) to display prices in real time on my sheet. (I also make a few calculations.) 
But, for reasons that I totally ignore,  and not always but very often, the price I see on my sheet has some delay compared to the price I see in my software. Sometimes, the latency of prices displayed in Excel can be up to several minutes. As Excel RTD is supposed to give data in real-time, it sounds like it stores the data somewhere when there is too much information. When I deactivate the link between Excel and my software, prices keep being updated on my sheet for a few moments (these "few moments" are equal to the latency between Excel and the software).

This is really annoying as I don't know why Excel RTD gives me prices with such a delay! My sheet has fewer than 300 filled cells, which is, in my opinion, absolutely nothing. 
Of course, my Excel throttle limit is set to 0 in order to get each update. 
I also changed my file from a `.xlsx` to a `.xlsb`,
but nothing changed apart from the file's size.

It really seems like Excel is storing the data somewhere, but I don't want this to happen; I want real time data.

- Using latest version of Office -

What is happening? 
How can I get my data in Excel in real time?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could consider adjusting the RTD Interval Throttle in Microsoft Excel
To set the throttle interval higher through the Excel object model:

1. In Excel, go to the Visual Basic Editor (by pressing ALT+F11 or clicking Visual Basic Editor from the Macromenu (Tools menu)).
2. In the Immediate window (press CTRL+G or click Immediate Window on the View menu), type this code: Application.RTD.ThrottleInterval = 1000
3. Make sure your cursor is on the line that you just typed, and then press ENTER.
4. To verify that it is set correctly, type this line of if code in the Immediate window: ?Application.RTD.ThrottleInterval
5. If you put your cursor at the end of this line and press ENTER, it should display 1000. Then you know that your throttle interval is set correctly.

Review this article to see if it helps:
   https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-xp/aa140060(v=office.10)#odc_xlrtdfaq_howconfigrtdthrottle

Comment: The thing is that I am dealing with high-frequency data, so I can't assume to miss even e few miliseconds of data.

Comment: Thank you very much for this article Bella, I saw that under a throttle interval of 5 miliseconds, Excel will lag and and will be missing a lot of updates. So I changed the interval to 6 and it seems to be working now. I'll continue to monitor it during the next days.

Comment: Ok, wait for your reply. If my reply is helpful, please mark it as an answer.

Comment: Well, I still have big latencies. It sounds like Excel stores data that he can't process in real-time. Therefore, each time excel lacks time to process the data, it saves it somewhere and the latency just keep increase over time. This is just what I understand, not the truth.